# $.post and $.ajax callbacks not running with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Bootstrap signing form and I'm using this code:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'process/register.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   dataType: "html",
   success: function(msg){
    alert('23');
   },
   error: function(error) {
     console.log("an error", error);
    }
 });
```

Yet nothing happens. The form works, the database has new additions, but the callback never runs.

As requested, this is the `register.php` code:

```
$email = $_POST['Email_address'];
$pword = $_POST['Password'];

$pword = md5($pword);

$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO users (`name`,`password`) VALUES ('" . $email . "','" . $pword . "')");
if($result != FALSE){
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
echo "!!!!!!!!!!";
```

In case it helps, here's the HTML form code:

```
  <form class="form-signin" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" id="regForm">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading" style="width:500px;">Register</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" name="Email_address" id="Email_address" autofocus required>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="Password" id="Password" required><br>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="regSubmit">Register</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure your server responds with an html datatype? Because this is what you're expecting in your ajax call, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . Maybe, your server processes the request and responds with some other type? More information would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe your form works without the ajax request? That would explain the new additions in your db. We never know unless we see more code. @sebastian_oe: wouldnt a wrong datatype fire the error function?

Comment: The form's action is set to `""`, so it's not despite the ajax request. I'm not sure what datatype my server accepts. I usually use `$.post` and it works fine. I did this to add an error callback.

Comment: Really the only difference between what I was doing and my normal ajax calls is this time I'm using Bootstrap. Although, here I used `$.ajax` for the error method, I did what I regularly do first, which is the `$.post`.

Comment: If you just want to add a error callback to $.post(), use $.post({...}).fail(function(error) { echo "false" });

Comment: Also, try removing dataType and jquery will make an intelligent guess.

Comment: Please do me a favor and use `dataType: 'text'` instead of html and see if it fires. EDIT: ah Gaurav was few seconds faster -.-

Comment: I changed it to text and I also removed it, each time it did nothing, although it posted to the database.

Comment: @JVE999 And your console also doesnt reveal anything?

Comment: It's been completely blank... Maybe it is has something to do with synchronous vs asynchronous? I thought I ran across that affecting callbacks somewhere, but I don't quite remember.

Comment: Oh wow, I just figured it out. I think bootstrap is doing something that blocks the callback, so it technically runs or something and it gets blocked. Adding `async:false` made it run.

Answer (score 0):

Use json ! :)

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'process/register.php',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       dataType: "json",
       error: function(error) {
         console.log("an error", error);
        }
     }).done(function(json){
      // your code here
    });
```

serverside :

```
$email = $_POST['Email_address'];
$pword = $_POST['Password'];

$pword = md5($pword);


$result = $db->query("INSERT INTO users (`name`,`password`) VALUES ('" . $email . "','" . $pword . "')");

$output = new stdClass();
if($result != false){
    $output->status="success";
} else {
    $output->status="fail";
    $output->message="Wrong password";
}
print json_encode($output);
```

Comment: I copied it verbatim and it does the same thing. It adds it to the database but does not run the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the JavaScript to:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'process/register.php',
   data: $(this).serialize(),
   dataType: "html",
   async:false,
   success: function(msg){
    alert('23');
   },
   error: function(error) {
     console.log("an error", error);
    }
 });
```

Solved it. (Adding the line `async:false`). However, it still refreshed. It turns out the real problem was the page was refreshing (with `async:true`, I think the page refreshed before the callback was run, changing it made the callback run first). Thus, this solved it, and the `async:false` is not needed:

```
$("#regForm").submit(function () {
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'process/register.php',
           data: $(this).serialize(),
           dataType: "html",
           success: function(msg){
                alert('23');
           },
           error: function(error) {
                console.log("an error", error);
           }
     });
     return false;
});
```

(Adding `return false` at the end of the submit function).

Comment: Strange, async:false, jQuery callbacks are called in async=true mode ?

Comment: Actually. Good point. The problem was that with `async:true` the page refreshed before the callback. With `async:false` the page refreshed after the callback. So, it really was the preventing the refreshing after submit.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you do no `echo 'any string';` in your php right?
`function(msg)` expects something in return, even simply echo 1 for success ( added to db ) or echo 0 ( failed to insert )

So you could do in your success handler ( note: ajax connected to the php and expexts a return value ) = success

```
success: function(msg) {
    if(msg == 'success') { 
        alert('yay'); 
    }
    else { 
        alert('fail');
    }
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't state guesses as an answer. comment your thoughts.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be about PHP but about JavaScript.

Comment: @razhial Not really a guess, more a mix, but my updated answer validates more to that and is a bit to much for a comment. Everyone really is generous with downvotes lol

Comment: @sebastian_oe It does, he has php involved also

Comment: I posted the php script.